# How to properly split a long table on two pages with `longtable` package?

Tags: tables, formatting, longtable

I want to split my table on two pages by using the `longtable` package and I want also to print `Continued on next page` at the bottom of first part and `continued from previous page` at the top of the second part.

Here my .csv file:

```
index,          pdes,    epoch_JDTDB,                 tp_JDTDB,                     a_km,                        e,                    w_deg,                   ta_deg,                   ma_deg,                  n_deg/d
    1,    459872    ,      2459600.5,    0.245955429393969E+07,    0.150902180397680E+09,    0.700936137135535E-01,    0.444423490130398E+02,    0.509894719093894E+02,    0.449518800380460E+02,    0.972856801473429E+00
    2,    1991 VG   ,      2459600.5,    0.245965301734296E+07,    0.154448562453878E+09,    0.524440272062934E-01,    0.981969077945011E+02,    0.305901193619353E+03,    0.310657729272394E+03,    0.939542405344313E+00
    3,    2000 SG344,      2459600.5,    0.245967142235446E+07,    0.146215475380197E+09,    0.668906906224866E-01,    0.107259306095888E+03,    0.280186369328737E+03,    0.287658863754547E+03,    0.102000471918105E+01
    4,    2003 YN107,      2459600.5,    0.245973765703815E+07,    0.147913409318582E+09,    0.138963447919681E-01,    0.352070216744272E+03,    0.221439015133514E+03,    0.222501180674322E+03,    0.100249189670507E+01
    5,    2006 JY26 ,      2459600.5,    0.245950771201134E+07,    0.151137260433216E+09,    0.831296262363333E-01,    0.317110762865456E+03,    0.995403784006208E+02,    0.900588991605521E+02,    0.970587901094867E+00
    6,    2006 QQ56 ,      2459600.5,    0.245948919576395E+07,    0.147356242165350E+09,    0.455957054639189E-01,    0.132721216278857E+03,    0.116944610798197E+03,    0.112215042556733E+03,    0.100818303543359E+01
    7,    2006 RH120,      2459600.5,    0.245941700549627E+07,    0.154561655457568E+09,    0.245007640852704E-01,    0.612989647862820E+02,    0.172580928455976E+03,    0.172211683048000E+03,    0.938511397040527E+00
    8,    2008 KT   ,      2459600.5,    0.245953461409501E+07,    0.151258200465874E+09,    0.848608221871707E-01,    0.342764067883614E+03,    0.729900449651001E+02,    0.638713820818490E+02,    0.969424068668380E+00
    9,    2010 JW34 ,      2459600.5,    0.245945998807400E+07,    0.146787030932466E+09,    0.546959172169960E-01,    0.935305817647752E+02,    0.146104139983164E+03,    0.142486542927059E+03,    0.101405302017029E+01
   10,    2010 VQ98 ,      2459600.5,    0.245964817443899E+07,    0.153049476036059E+09,    0.271228099514851E-01,    0.278481297592747E+02,    0.312325623997152E+03,    0.314592246885651E+03,    0.952454901870152E+00
   11,    2011 BL45 ,      2459600.5,    0.245962311850242E+07,    0.155240281637318E+09,    0.209159127584399E-01,    0.290052626627032E+03,    0.338027420043348E+03,    0.338911319571078E+03,    0.932364134430259E+00
   12,    2011 MD   ,      2459600.5,    0.245970716287812E+07,    0.158025828430105E+09,    0.370354171841830E-01,    0.277534761279446E+03,    0.258982216976828E+03,    0.263169231962853E+03,    0.907820693971977E+00
   13,    2011 UD21 ,      2459600.5,    0.245959546831742E+07,    0.146394319819154E+09,    0.303901572781969E-01,    0.232201197921950E+03,    0.544610304321270E+01,    0.512293786480974E+01,    0.101813613801581E+01
   14,    2012 FC71 ,      2459600.5,    0.245944384209223E+07,    0.147753060700911E+09,    0.881238923958131E-01,    0.265651355261692E+02,    0.160837550414405E+03,    0.157304006796337E+03,    0.100412426689864E+01
   15,    2012 LA   ,      2459600.5,    0.245963284323666E+07,    0.155629244985498E+09,    0.215419232343968E-01,    0.313658884228480E+03,    0.328692090671317E+03,    0.329957307349960E+03,    0.928870940217809E+00
   16,    2012 TF79 ,      2459600.5,    0.245944560454553E+07,    0.157051642075687E+09,    0.382015078336360E-01,    0.105571935872503E+03,    0.144528321377656E+03,    0.141927692789605E+03,    0.916280553685583E+00
   17,    2013 BS45 ,      2459600.5,    0.245966822620292E+07,    0.148335781949418E+09,    0.837159284910235E-01,    0.234029113553501E+03,    0.283197371646046E+03,    0.292394810967472E+03,    0.998213189555839E+00
   18,    2013 GH66 ,      2459600.5,    0.245957636408977E+07,    0.157244355912090E+09,    0.445528650254918E-01,    0.234586878618380E+03,    0.240970375512773E+02,    0.220746219650596E+02,    0.914596622082036E+00
   19,    2013 RZ53 ,      2459600.5,    0.245958720069335E+07,    0.152067298076445E+09,    0.282800271702146E-01,    0.481464493894571E+02,    0.135328686885348E+02,    0.127899088014129E+02,    0.961697412888642E+00
   20,    2014 DJ80 ,      2459600.5,    0.245973661930365E+07,    0.146164397997344E+09,    0.670433424964364E-01,    0.358904031049864E+03,    0.216342051797593E+03,    0.221084883530397E+03,    0.102053942931091E+01
   21,    2014 QD364,      2459600.5,    0.245961356101330E+07,    0.147456947362464E+09,    0.415090568064656E-01,    0.183186617343013E+03,    0.345705713911763E+03,    0.346845595104856E+03,    0.100715040926994E+01
   22,    2014 WX202,      2459600.5,    0.245971504151086E+07,    0.154922831557422E+09,    0.587821123517639E-01,    0.980648925268380E+02,    0.246588855987646E+03,    0.252877189048973E+03,    0.935231342276537E+00
   23,    2015 JD3  ,      2459600.5,    0.245979799400818E+07,    0.158338861690838E+09,    0.788218128012126E-02,    0.103666631683835E+03,    0.181222876079030E+03,    0.181242267009019E+03,    0.905129905663600E+00
   24,    2015 XZ378,      2459600.5,    0.245972406905748E+07,    0.151814338975956E+09,    0.348266028265004E-01,    0.195766056131395E+03,    0.237455280394632E+03,    0.240866819389946E+03,    0.964102041686692E+00
   25,    2016 RD34 ,      2459600.5,    0.245960864268907E+07,    0.156518816441756E+09,    0.346884806290049E-01,    0.596425786776479E+00,    0.351958848081779E+03,    0.352500881593116E+03,    0.920963374354774E+00
   26,    2016 YR   ,      2459600.5,    0.245971110581366E+07,    0.153612415665988E+09,    0.673593654181797E-01,    0.160725976990122E+03,    0.247944300513107E+03,    0.255231513831913E+03,    0.947224044578286E+00
   27,    2017 BN93 ,      2459600.5,    0.245957590474879E+07,    0.156248041247550E+09,    0.514444699164082E-01,    0.339131486672269E+03,    0.251285655473790E+02,    0.227102325947081E+02,    0.923358432017030E+00
   28,    2017 FT102,      2459600.5,    0.245944372982097E+07,    0.155344111619768E+09,    0.589415445705560E-01,    0.246403161444080E+03,    0.149575212153502E+03,    0.146020372689207E+03,    0.931429520565171E+00
   29,    2017 HU49 ,      2459600.5,    0.245943859139239E+07,    0.145320084181079E+09,    0.550695712685786E-01,    0.315161871980752E+02,    0.168038875328450E+03,    0.166676230006317E+03,    0.102944638009368E+01
   30,    2018 PK21 ,      2459600.5,    0.245963016870613E+07,    0.147143192377718E+09,    0.809504986795553E-01,    0.169941300142329E+03,    0.324952037144644E+03,    0.330023526673465E+03,    0.101037346208080E+01
   31,    2018 PN22 ,      2459600.5,    0.245964001533153E+07,    0.148878145171218E+09,    0.441155460208655E-01,    0.163691635984829E+03,    0.317433045076963E+03,    0.320770624202571E+03,    0.992763423107931E+00
   32,    2019 FV2  ,      2459600.5,    0.245943637351810E+07,    0.157518620840742E+09,    0.222209832820111E-01,    0.261530436252940E+03,    0.150971465669649E+03,    0.149717649868919E+03,    0.912208975255747E+00
   33,    2019 GF1  ,      2459600.5,    0.245943235521925E+07,    0.148185016910306E+09,    0.483846257108554E-01,    0.330041500831176E+03,    0.169179721397270E+03,    0.168100553011994E+03,    0.999736966313342E+00
   34,    2019 KJ2  ,      2459600.5,    0.245949827968751E+07,    0.158158349636612E+09,    0.265217997937862E-01,    0.314100160250270E+03,    0.957108407828916E+02,    0.926811063618908E+02,    0.906679935775918E+00
   35,    2019 PO1  ,      2459600.5,    0.245976236466962E+07,    0.154980165970103E+09,    0.610251706846550E-01,    0.218594213105760E+03,    0.205557231128277E+03,    0.208703084314892E+03,    0.934712411548874E+00
   36,    2020 CD3  ,      2459600.5,    0.245964055404853E+07,    0.153927447429573E+09,    0.124119645956147E-01,    0.132237775849684E+03,    0.321293267894109E+03,    0.322176256449857E+03,    0.944317614311828E+00
   37,    2020 FA1  ,      2459600.5,    0.245942693660613E+07,    0.153683604227674E+09,    0.312125634356505E-01,    0.294791535604644E+03,    0.165222558829580E+03,    0.164289201946996E+03,    0.946565968120746E+00
   38,    2020 GE   ,      2459600.5,    0.245977309300938E+07,    0.150456297997289E+09,    0.394721369158331E-01,    0.290603400967119E+03,    0.190496156549044E+03,    0.191344761278848E+03,    0.977184645704984E+00
   39,    2020 HF4  ,      2459600.5,    0.245956204935473E+07,    0.152170464199802E+09,    0.242954013466628E-01,    0.698474821861645E+02,    0.386547752164136E+02,    0.369402879300588E+02,    0.960719584077720E+00
   40,    2020 HO5  ,      2459600.5,    0.245945224486759E+07,    0.148228891552893E+09,    0.235918887764843E-01,    0.341938234913160E+03,    0.149541883354307E+03,    0.148150334881044E+03,    0.999293127170340E+00
   41,    2020 MU1  ,      2459600.5,    0.245959361545908E+07,    0.153269851289492E+09,    0.410962934675716E-01,    0.965188360436188E+02,    0.710848612786732E+01,    0.654307763403493E+01,    0.950401444961766E+00
   42,    2020 RB4  ,      2459600.5,    0.245941602449114E+07,    0.155716321955468E+09,    0.318060742935540E-01,    0.275174554003549E+03,    0.171746079494735E+03,    0.171210227112294E+03,    0.928091908604127E+00
   43,    2020 VN1  ,      2459600.5,    0.245977387363191E+07,    0.146598676215311E+09,    0.639786305183112E-01,    0.300327912029078E+03,    0.183395099503827E+03,    0.183851006471909E+03,    0.101600797992378E+01
   44,    2020 WY   ,      2459600.5,    0.245941436932402E+07,    0.152573895524419E+09,    0.285563468083888E-01,    0.287367535530617E+03,    0.178214778516651E+03,    0.178110611366167E+03,    0.956911645141437E+00
   45,    2021 AK5  ,      2459600.5,    0.245960096976913E+07,    0.153883234554023E+09,    0.200291486058647E-01,    0.106272329030983E+03,    0.359537963721016E+03,    0.359556197536796E+03,    0.944724617674365E+00
   46,    2021 CZ4  ,      2459600.5,    0.245952260029562E+07,    0.156125208450099E+09,    0.127510194612455E-01,    0.276610968913450E+02,    0.734107432492926E+02,    0.720142521003868E+02,    0.924448336130501E+00
   47,    2021 GM1  ,      2459600.5,    0.245951518159400E+07,    0.146448569482789E+09,    0.251744356006535E-01,    0.422586455641710E+02,    0.897016401316863E+02,    0.868174896980165E+02,    0.101757046064737E+01
   48,    2021 LF6  ,      2459600.5,    0.245954841464668E+07,    0.146922210225726E+09,    0.376873564671643E-01,    0.748273000196580E+02,    0.562803660240619E+02,    0.527444328626688E+02,    0.101265383653239E+01
   49,    2021 RZ3  ,      2459600.5,    0.245971672035841E+07,    0.151247200249468E+09,    0.534340157484946E-01,    0.224932804594716E+03,    0.241821660186638E+03,    0.247320895670051E+03,    0.969529829982518E+00
   50,    2021 RG12 ,      2459600.5,    0.245950139770560E+07,    0.156344638609306E+09,    0.398352652964655E-01,    0.210277645516152E+02,    0.959750969086374E+02,    0.914221460756280E+02,    0.922502820234366E+00
   51,    2021 VH2  ,      2459600.5,    0.245960125240315E+07,    0.151499420286046E+09,    0.781099311214379E-01,    0.126995065106977E+03,    0.359146434545383E+03,    0.359272343623765E+03,    0.967109691573498E+00
   52,    2021 VX22 ,      2459600.5,    0.245945464036108E+07,    0.151091730973574E+09,    0.546343435510506E-01,    0.329828043095979E+03,    0.145319103606594E+03,    0.141633595750957E+03,    0.971026644544897E+00
   53,    2022 BY39 ,      2459600.5,    0.245953050383236E+07,    0.150340931578298E+09,    0.790169133544520E-01,    0.435999438035180E+02,    0.771837059292549E+02,    0.684779261125277E+02,    0.978309647889179E+00
```

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[%
            % chose this for a4
            a4paper,textwidth=15.5cm,textheight=26.0cm,%
            %
            inner=2.3cm,% 1.5cm,% 1cm,%
            %hcentering,%
            vcentering,%
            marginparwidth=2.2cm,% 2.8cm%,% 2.2cm,%
            %showframe%
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{float}

\sisetup{
  round-mode=figures,
  round-precision = 3,
  exponent-product = {\hspace{-1pt}\times\hspace{-2pt}},
}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Title chapter}

\section{title section}
text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text.

\begin{table}[h]

  \caption{The table}
  \label{tab:label}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{
        @{} 
        c 
        l
        S[table-format=7.1]
        *3{S[table-format=1.3e1]}
        S[table-format=1.3e1]
        @{}
    }
    \toprule
      {\thead{idx.}}
    & {\thead[l]{pdes}}
    & {\thead{epoch\\ (JDTDB)}}
    & {\thead{a (km)}}
    & {\thead{e}}
    & {\thead{w (deg)}}
    & {\thead{ta (deg)}} \\
    \midrule
    \csvreader[
      late after line = \\,
    ]{Appendices/Appendix_B/NEA_filtered_data.csv}{}{%
      \csvcoli  & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv
      & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii
    }
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The above code prints the table on a new page but I want that the table is printed after the text and continues on the new page. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use one of the long tables: `longtable`, `xltabular` or `supertabular`. The solution below is based on [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable); in the code, `\endfirsthead`, `\endhead`, `\endfoot`, and `\endlastfoot` are macros to indicate which lines of the table should appear on the first, subsequent or the last pages.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[%
            % chose this for a4
            a4paper,textwidth=15.5cm,textheight=26.0cm,%
            %
            inner=2.3cm,% 1.5cm,% 1cm,%
            %hcentering,%
            vcentering,%
            marginparwidth=2.2cm,% 2.8cm%,% 2.2cm,%
            %showframe%
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}

\sisetup{
  round-mode=figures,
  round-precision = 3,
  exponent-product = {\hspace{-1pt}\times\hspace{-2pt}},
}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Title chapter}

\section{title section}
text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text.

\begin{longtable}{
    @{} 
    c 
    l
    S[table-format=7.1]
    *3{S[table-format=1.3e1]}
    S[table-format=1.3e1]
    @{}
}
\caption{The table} \\
\toprule
  {\thead{idx.}}
& {\thead[l]{pdes}}
& {\thead{epoch\\ (JDTDB)}}
& {\thead{a (km)}}
& {\thead{e}}
& {\thead{w (deg)}}
& {\thead{ta (deg)}} \\
\midrule \endfirsthead
\caption{The table \textit{(continued from previous page)}} \\
\toprule
  {\thead{idx.}}
& {\thead[l]{pdes}}
& {\thead{epoch\\ (JDTDB)}}
& {\thead{a (km)}}
& {\thead{e}}
& {\thead{w (deg)}}
& {\thead{ta (deg)}} \\
\midrule \endhead
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{7}{r@{}}{\textit{Continues on the next page ...}} \endfoot
\bottomrule \endlastfoot
\csvreader[
  late after line = \\,
]{NEA_filtered_data.csv}{}{%
  \csvcoli  & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv
  & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii
}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Celdor. Can you kindly show how to manage the options of `siunitx` package to write the last two columns without using the current notation? For instance I want to get `44.10` instead of `0.441x10^2`. I want to apply this change to the last two columns.

Comment: It's enabled by the postfix `e1` in formatting `S`. For instance, change `S[table-format=1.3e1]` to `S[table-format=1.3]`.