# LaTeX csvreader/longtable: Put long narrow table multiple times on page

Tags: tables, longtable, csvsimple

I have a very narrow table (2 columns) imported from a csv using csvreader that currently stretches over 3 pages.
This looks a bit weird, so I would like to have all three pages of the table on the same page.

Is there some option for this? I can't seem to find one.

One possible solution that I thought about was to just use `\begin{multicols}{3}`, but I'm not sure if that will work and it's also not very elegant.

Update: Tried `\begin{multicols}{3}`, but longtable doesn't like it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\csvreader[
    longtable = c|c,
    table head = Distanz (Pixel) & Graustufen \\\hline\endhead
]{im_171.csv}{}%
{\csvlinetotablerow}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could do it as suggested by Celdor at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/666245/17360 but in multiple columns with the help of `supertabular`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try splitting the table and working with minipages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
    \begin{longtable}{cc}
        A & B\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\ 
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2   
    \end{longtable}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
    \begin{longtable}{cc}
        A & B\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\ 
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2   
    \end{longtable}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
    \begin{longtable}{cc}
        A & B\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\ 
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2\\
        1 & 2   
    \end{longtable}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I import the data using csvreader, so that won't work. It's also not very elegant to just split the table^^

Comment: Maybe you can provide a bit more details such that I do not need to guess the question in full ;-) You could start with a MWE.

Comment: Added one, but not sure if that really helps :)